# Is there any way to run .net core unit tests in a docker container through VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, unit-testing, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am currently looking for ways on how to test my .net core unit/integration test projects inside a docker container.

I already know about `dotnet test` and I would know how to create the correct Dockerfile to get this working, but I'm looking for a way to do this through VS2019 directly, instead of doing it via cli or vs code.

I'd like to do this for potentially debugging unit tests, as well as for making use of the nice VS unit test session overview.

Essentially, I would have to teach the embedded unit test start / debug buttons to trigger the dotnet test, and potentially attaching the debugger.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't supported in VS 2019, but there is now support in VS 2022: [Remote Testing in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022)